# MySQL Workbench Failing to Connect to Server (Windows)

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

There are many errors I have found across the web that deal with MySQL connection errors, but I have found none that address this specific problem that I am having. In short, I have the newest version of the MySQL Server installed (8.0), I have verified it is running in my Services tab, and I can connect to the server via the MySQL client just fine. However, I cannot open a local connection in Workbench.

When I click on the local instance, it hangs until I manually stop it. I then get the aforementioned error

[image]

I then went and ran a diagnostic of the server in the MySQL Installer, which reported that everything is working fine (unless I am reading it wrong)

[image]

The logs of said diagnostic also report that the server is installed, functional, and running.

[image]

I then checked made sure the server was running in Services

[image]

After that, I verified that I could connect to the client, and that I could use the database I was working with (info redacted due to it being company property lol)

[image]

Additionally, I also made a new connection on Workbench on port 3307 instead of the standard 3306.

[image]

When I click on this, I can enter into the connection without getting the "Cannot access a disposed object" error. However, this connection still cannot connect to the server.

[image]

I also saw that some people were having success by navigating into `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin` and running `mysqld --install`. This appeared to be beneficial, but ended up doing nothing.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this without completely uninstalling everything? Everything was working fine yesterday but has suddenly stopped as of this morning.

Comment: you have **two** mysql server, and for me is not clear which you are addressing or hat access what , stop one server and sse if gets you anywhere, else stop the second

Comment: @nbk I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Where are you seeing that I have two sql servers running? If you are referring to the picture of the two local connections, those aren't servers, but connection tabs listening to two different ports.

Comment: the services screenshot shows 2 mysql services one for 80 and one for something else